# How can Spring boot/Application.java pick up Mongo AbstractMongoConfiguration in another package?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to keep my classes organized into packages. Using the following example:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

I have Application.java in  "my.main.package"
I define my own implementation of AbstractMongoConfiguration below:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration;

import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

@Configuration
public class MyMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration{
    @Override
    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new MongoClient("remotehost:27018");
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "mydb";
    }
}
```

If I put the class within the same package as my Application.java, then it works. If I put MyMongoConfig in its own package i.e "my.config.package.settings", then running Application.java appears to use the default MongoDB connection settings without using "MyMongoConfig". Why is my application not automatically finding the "MyMongoConfig" when its in a different package? Is there a proper way or possibility to do this without shoving them both in the same package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It is recommended](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class) that the main Spring Boot application class to be located in a root package above other classes so that the base "search package" to be the root one. All packages from the root will be scanned for configuration classes.

If you choose to place some other configuration classes in other packages, I believe these needs to be specified. For example, if you have your main application class in package "demo" and your Mongo configuration class in package "another.demo", the `@ComponentScan` annotation for your main application class would need to look like:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"another.demo", "demo"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
```

Comment: I currently have Application.java in package "demo.main" and the config in my post in "demo.main.config". (The two packages are peers to each other under src/main/java. It looks like I am getting the following error: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: this Mongo has been closed. This does not happen when the config file are in the same package. Is there some other annotation I must add or something I must do?

Comment: No, that should be enough. What is your code for Application.java and what code are you using to access Mongo, that throws the exception?

Comment: Application.java has no beans or any lines related to my MyMongoConfig. It is annotated with Configuration ,ComponentScan EnableAutoConfiguration. I tried ComponentScan (basePackages={"demo.main", "demo.config"} (i moved the MyMongoConfig to demo.config). Code using to access is a "UserRepository.java" class that extends MongoRepository and is in the same package as Application.java (demo.main).

Comment: Could you share the code you mentioned? I've tested the simplest scenario I could have imagined and made the suggestions based on that. It would be much simpler if you can share what you have so far that doesn't work so I can test that and probably make other suggestions if I can replicate it. So, the more details/code you provide the quicker the investigation.